# Generating complex controlled image data

Tags: dataset, conv-neural-network, random-generation, image-processing

In order to demonstrate properties of statistical models it is often useful to generate data, which is messy, but messy in a controlled way which is well-understood by the generator. For example, to demonstrate the advantage of a more general Gaussian Mixture Modelling compared to $k$-means clustering, you might generate several slightly overlapping clusters with distinct spreads; see for example [this Wikimedia image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#/media/File:ClusterAnalysis_Mouse.svg).

I would like to test certain statistical properties of neural networks, especially convolutional. Data in low dimensions, with simple features, does not seem appropriate to me: this will fail to capture the actual power of the model, and be (heuristically) less likely to tell you things about the model that apply to real world applications.

Therefore I am interested in, either, existing artificial data sets, or generating complex image data myself in a controlled way.

My questions are:

1. Are there already complex generated image data sets freely available?
2. Are there standard succesful methods for generating complex image data in a controlled manner?

Comment: If you're trying to demonstrate the power of CNNs for image tasks, certainly real photos would be ideal for that.

Comment: @Sycorax, that is not what I am trying to demonstrate. I want to look at other statistical properties: the way errors are distributed, the quality of the predictions (defined in various ways), the sensitivity to overfitting (the difference between more epochs over the same data rather than generating new training data at every step). The point of using generated data rather than real is that I have fine control over what the input *is* and what I want it to be.

Comment: Well, you're certainly within your rights to demand that someone give you an answer about how to do something that I've never encountered in the literature. On the other hand, you could consider how to design experiments which measure these phenomena wrt modifications of real images. There's lots of literature about how to solve real problems with images, but not much about how to solve imaginary ones. For example, a hot topic right now is "adversarial images" which are normal images with imperceptible noise that dramatically shifts the classification.